# Django. Изоляция глобальных переменных для пользователей

Tags: django, сессия

В проекте Django для разных представлений `view` используются общие глобальные переменные. Например, 
функции `menu` и `listing` используют глобальную переменную `NON_APPROVED`:

```
NON_APPROVED = Entries.objects.filter(approved=False) # глобальная переменная QuerySet
...

def menu(request):
    global NON_APPROVED
    ...
    context = { 'NON_APPROVED_CNT': NON_APPROVED.counter() } # количество экземпляров
    return context

def listing(request):
    global NON_APPROVED
    ... 
    context = { 'NON_APPROVED': NON_APPROVED } # список QuerySet
    context.update(menu(request))
    return render(request, '/template.html', context)
```

В данном случае глобальная переменная `NON_APPROVED` для всех пользователей имеет одно значение. Такой подход был использован в связи с предположением, что сессия для каждого пользователя полностью изолирована. Оказалось, что такое предположение неверно, и глобальные переменные видны всем работающим пользователям. При этом, имеется состояние "гонки", когда любой пользователь изменяет их значение.

А необходимо, чтобы для разных пользователей значения `NON_APPROVED` были уникальными.

**Какие для этой цели есть общепринятые приемы, в том числе рекомендуемые Django, либо, просто, подходящие решения для изоляции глобальных переменных по группам пользователей или для отдельных пользователей??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы, глобальные переменные для всех пользователей одни. На то они и глобальные. Происходит следующее. Когда пользователь производит HTTP запрос, то выполняется только функция, но никак не код, который до нее. Поэтому линия 1 в вашем примере теоретически может выполниться только один раз, и переменная будет одна для всех. А может быть ещё «хуже»: если сервер multithreaded, то таких глобальных переменных будет несколько, и один и тот же пользователь будет «перескакивать» с одной на другую.

Если хотите записывать информацию связанную с сессией, то в Django для этого есть механизм. [Вот документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/). Но если есть перспектива скалинга (то есть программа будет выполняться на нескольких серверах), локальная сессия не подходит, и нужно использовать либо базу данных, либо, если данные не важны, использовать кэш, к примеру Redis.